# How to import a non-structured flat file into Python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-import, flat-file, flat

I'm trying to import a .db file into pandas. The file is ordered as:

---

```
Person 1

Characteristic 1: Value 

Characteristic 2: Value


Person 2

Characteristic 1: Value
```

Etc

---

I want to import the data into  pandas and have the persons as rows with their different characteristics in the columns like this:

---

```
Person Characteristic 1 Characteristic 2

Person 1 Value Value

Person 2 Value Value
```

Etc

---

I've tried to look around but only found advice for importing normal flat files where the columns are already specified in the file before import.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you know the file delimiter? or is the delimiter whitespace?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Does your input look exactly like your example, or is this just an illustration?  In this case, the specifics may matter (like whitespace, placing of colons, etc.).  The more "real" you can make your example (while keeping it small and contained), the more helpful the answers will be.

Comment: The file looks like the example above. There will be a name and then underneath that certain characteristics for that person. Then the next person, and the next and so on.

I don't really know the delimiter. Looks like it is just whitespace  after stating the value for a characteristic, it goes to the next line and states the next one

Comment: did you open it up in a text editor? there is absolutely no comma, tab or pipe delimiter?  then i think a regex approach will be best with the python CSV module before populating it into sql.

Comment: In NotePad it looks exactly the same yes. Would you mind elaborating on your approach? I'm not sure I know how to do that

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. As written your question is too broad unless you are looking for an algorithmic answer - if so please specify that.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- input is a line oriented text file
- empty lines are to be ignored
- lines containing no colon(`':'`) declare a new record
- lines containing colons declare attributes for the current record

That is not a file format that pandas can directly process, but Python can easily build a list of records, that will later feed a dataframe:

```
records = []
current = None
fieldnames = ['Person']

with open('inputfile') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) != 0:            # ignore empty lines
            if ':' in line:           # a characteristic line
                attr, value = line.split(':', 1)
                attr = attr.strip()
                current[attr] = value.strip()
                if not attr in fieldnames:
                    fieldnames.append(attr)
            else:                                      # a person line
                current = {'Person': line}
                records.append(current)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = fieldnames, data = records)
```

With your sample data, it gives as expected:

```
     Person Characteristic 1 Characteristic 2
0  Person 1            Value            Value
1  Person 2            Value              NaN
```